# timer interval gets double after every tick

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to visible panel if internet is connected and also hide when the user is offline in c# WinForms.

What i have tried it works well for first two timer ticks. If internet is disconnected panel will appear and disappear when connected back to internet.

After testing application twice when i disconnect wifi third time, the panel appear after 10 seconds while i have set the interval to 5 seconds(5000) in timer properties and similarly panel disappear after 10 seconds if i connect wifi.

and this interval keeps increased as like 5 to 10 and then 10 to 20 seconds.

Below is my code i am working to achieve this functionality.

```
    public static async Task<bool> CheckForInternetConnection()
    {
        bool result = false;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                using (client.OpenRead("http://google.com/generate_204"))
                    result = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                result = false;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }


    public async void GetResult()
    {
        var get = await CheckForInternetConnection();
        if (get)
        {
            lbl_warning.Visible = false; //connected
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_warning.Visible = true; //not connected  
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetResult();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

I want to check for internet after every 5 seconds and this should work quick and without delay,
also guide me is this a good way of using timer.
I would like to know if timer can be used in different other ways from performance perspective.

Comment: This worked for me.  Any other code you're not showing?

Comment: No. That's it. But it works for starting few tick and that 5 seconds interval gets too long to display warning label.

Comment: To detect whether the problem is in the timer or in the WebBrowser, have you tried to do something else in `timer1_tick`?, for instance `Debug.WriteLine("Tick " + Datetime.UtcNow);` Does the interval also increase? What happens if you `Debug.WriteLine` the time just before and just after `Client.OpenRead`?